# memory leak due to Oracle JDBC driver(ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar) on OpenShift/jbossews/Tomcat7.x

Tags: java, oracle11g, tomcat7, connection-pooling, openshift-cartridge

I am using openShift/jbossews(tomcat-7) and spring 4.x & for  Oracle 11g(ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar) database connectivity configured using tomcat JNDI datasource.

When I try to re-deploy the  code(war) using CI(jenkin build)..in the application some Oracle classes gives memory leak notification in server logs.

did anybody faced this type of issue ,please help me to clear this SEVERE error. 
Is there anything I can do to clean these?

Openshift Tomcat server logs:-

```
Sep 30, 2015 1:35:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Sep 30, 2015 1:35:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
    Sep 30, 2015 1:35:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
    INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/546d3268d14ee9564d002626/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war
    Sep 30, 2015 1:35:34 AM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory performJNDILookup
    WARNING: The name "jdbc/DMDataSource" can not be found in the InitialContext.
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    Sep 30, 2015 1:35:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Error listenerStart
    Sep 30, 2015 1:35:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
    Sep 30, 2015 1:35:36 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
    SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@cf69687]) and a value of type [java.lang.Class] (value [class oracle.sql.AnyDataFactory]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
    Sep 30, 2015 1:35:36 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
    SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@11147fb7]) and a value of type [java.lang.Class] (value [class oracle.sql.TypeDescriptorFactory]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
    Sep 30, 2015 1:35:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
    INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/546d3268d14ee9564d002626/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 23,890 ms
    Sep 30, 2015 1:35:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.3.183.129-8080"]
    Sep 30, 2015 1:35:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 24114 ms
```

Comment: execute `java -jar ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar` to get praticular JDBC driver version. Possibly you can download newer version of the driver from Oracle site. But most probably it is the application, who is leaking the resources, not a driver.

Comment: @ibre5041 try that also but dame issue.